# Where can I get formail for OS X El Capitan (10.11)?

Tags: email, command-line, homebrew, macos

I was using formail in a utility script, but it disappeared when I upgraded to OS X El Capitan (10.11)? Apparently, it and procmail are gone.

What's a good way to get formail? Build it from source? It's not in homebrew (yet).

Comment: It should be in the [homebrew](http://brew.sh/)  `procmail` package

Answer (score 5):

It’s included with the procmail formula:

```
brew update && brew install procmail
```